# Viewing Oracle log files

Tags: oracle, toad, logfiles, sql-navigator

I have an administrative account in Oracle 9i. I need to run some SELECT scripts on the database in SQL Navigator. The scripts are written on the fly in the 'SQL Editor' window of SQL Navigator and are not saved after the running. 
The questions are:

1) What does the log file for this kind of scripts (which use the SELECT clause) contain? E.g., account name, timestamp, or whatever? Does it keep the text of the script?

2) Can I view the contents of these log files from SQL Navigator or TOAD? I mean using another query (something like 'SELECT * FROM gv$log') which allow me to view the log file? Or using a special tool for this purpose?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Nothing. DML gets logged, not Selects, (unless you have auditing enabled). Having said that, for a limited time all run sql can be found in v$sql.

2) I think they are not very human readable and I can't imagine why would you want to do it. (Redo) logs exist for the database to be able to reconstruct transactions after it crashes. They're not intended for humans to read.

Comment: Why would I want to view the log files? Well, out of curiosity and for better understanding. But now that I know they are not human readable, I wouldn't.)) And your mention of the 'v$sql' view also helped. Thank you, Michal.